# Can I mq_send to reply after I mq_recieve?

Tags: linux, message-queue

I have one or more daemon app running and to communicate with it I have a client app. The client app is something simple executed on the command line. Chances are only one will be up at a given moment. When I do a command such as `daemon update-config` the client does mq_open and sends the command. Some commands like `list` I'd want results. It appears that if I run `mq_send` in my daemon after I receive I may receive the message within the daemon app.

What's the best way to send the reply to the client w/o accidentally processing it in the daemon? After a quick lookup there didn't appear to be an obvious solution so I do `sleep(1)` which seems to solve my problem completely even though it's a 'hack'. Whats the best solution? is sleep the most understandable and straightforward solution? I don't feel like generating random/unique values, passing it in and opening another mq to send it. The sleep for a second feels like the best solution but I wonder what your solutions may be.

Answer (score 2):

When using messaging systems, you can do RPC calls even if it is not the best paradigm to use messaging in general. The general approach to RPC with messaging is:

- have distinct queues for requests and for replies (the latter ones can be ephemeral queues, created for each request, or persistent queues);
- give to each message a unique ID, that will be used in the replies to identify which message it was replying to. (it's called correlation_id in AMQP for example).

I do guess that you can use the same approach with Posix queues as well.